# Need to deploy the same app to multiple contexts, each with a different database Tomcat7

Tags: java, deployment, tomcat7, datasource, jndi

How to deploy the same application to multiple contexts, each with a different database.
Using Tomcat7.0.54. We have 3 different environments like Development, Quality, Production. All the 3 environments have 3 different database configurations.

Normally apache-tomcat-7.0.54\conf\context.xml file. Sample D config.

```
<!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
<!--
<Manager pathname="" />
-->

<!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
     on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
<!--
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
-->
<Resource name="java:jboss/datasources/letterDatasource"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        username="admin"
        password="admin"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        url="xxx xxxx xxxxx xx"
        maxActive="8"
        maxIdle="4"/>
```

How to do the above programmatically or efficiently instead of changing in every server context.xml file.?
i am not using spring. just normal web application using seam 2.3 with jsf and richfaces.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your data base properties in an environment.property file, which will be different for each stage. Specified environment will take their specific environmental properties.